# En ggplot ¿como elimino de un gráfico los valores nulos?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tengo los siguientes datos, al hacer
`table(datos$sede)`

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ese 1 asumo que es un dato perdido, ya que los datos fueron creados con google form.

Al graficar, con el siguiente código

```
p <- ggplot(data =datos ,aes(sede, fill = sede))+ 
  geom_bar() +
  labs(x = " ", y = " ") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),legend.position = "down")
print(p)
```

resulta lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito eliminar la primera columna, roja, que no representa nada relevante.
Tengo un set de datos y grafico con un for todos los parametros, y en todos se repite el problema

```
for (i in datos)
{
  
  p <- ggplot(data =datos,aes(i, fill = i))+ 
    geom_bar() +
    labs(title = nombres[i], x = " ", y = " ") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
  
  print(p)
}
```

Muchas gracias, excelente comunidad

Comment: Entiendo que lo que buscas es eliminar ese caso extraño que tienes, lo ideal es limpiarlos de la base: `datos <- datos[datos$sede %in% c('La Serena', 'Santiago'), ]`, pero también puedes hacerlo desde `ggplot`, `ggplot(data=datos[datos$sede %in% c('La Serena', 'Santiago'), ], ...)`

Comment: Gracias! funciona, pero mi problema es que tengo esto dentro del for para otros datos... entonces lo preciso que me ayudaría sería algo como un not null, !="na" o algo así... ya que como está en el for, los datos que me sirven siempre varian, por eso me sive m´sa una negación. Conoces alguna manera? 

Muchas gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: sigo tu blog igual, tienes excelente info, estoy graficando gracias a tus post!

Comment: Hola Claudio, podría ser algo así: datos[ !is,na(datos$sede), ] también. Saludos. –